# Unable to read html from some websites

Tags: html, http, haskell, encoding, web-scraping

```
openUrl :: String -> MaybeT IO String
openUrl url = 
    case parseURI url of
      Nothing -> fail ""
      Just u -> liftIO (getResponseBody =<< simpleHTTP (mkRequest GET u))
```

I am trying to learn Haskell and I started with a very simple html **scraper** . It works for most sites but I just encountered some sites that I can not read and I am wondering why.

```
runMaybeT $ openUrl "http://google.com"

Just "<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html;charset=utf-8\">\n<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>\n<H1>302 Moved</H1>\nThe document has moved\n<A HREF=\"http://www.google.de/?gfe_rd=cr&amp;ei=270MU9u8LM_esgaQ_YDgDw\">here</A>.\r\n</BODY></HTML>\r\n"
```

as expected and it also works for most sites. But for some sites like

```
runMaybeT $ openUrl "http://kickass.to"
```

It results in weird encoding.

```
....223\250ns\147\214\203\235`\188\&0f\SO\182vw\v\200\&0m\195\181\143CY[\223\ETB\n\175\209\240\155\160\240\157\248\189x\231Xa\239\187\194\DEL$\SI\144S\SYN\210\t\DEL\DC2\213\129\DLE \FS\153<\178\135a\239{\246**7y\246:z2t\238m\151\191\181\181\245]\225\205\168\240\221\195^~\186\&8\221\162q\191\233\205\254\198O\225\SYN\233\170\228\ETX\CANt7\203\219\141\&2\175\167\240\221\153\DC1\246\138p\205#\237\250&/\191\193\143\ESColDg\211\&6N1\199\200\128\199\231\&8\154\218\182\231#\"bw\163\188\193\248\b\249'14\250\184\183\243\191 \GS\DC4\182\216\171R\t\130\219\204n O\251\EOT7\206v\176\237mw\183\253mc\187\SI\DLE1\231j\ETX\SOH\130]\215\222G\188\223\CANg\164\131\143mJD\181q\189\235\191q\174\252\235]\250\231_\255z\128\188MzZ\252\133\255X\252\229_\255\186\186\222\DC24\SYNA\DEL\FS\135\193\214\239\219\252\GSwW\253\SI\n#=\130\144\131\237j\236\ACK\SI \234mm\163\139}<\207\EOT\133\183Eh0\138\FS\158\187*>\209\161\238\238\155\254\\x\208\200P#\208\129\204\210\136\175\217\142\247\214vL\r\182\177/)0\ACK)11r\197\136\135\206#\196&\223\NUL\223\237\141\174\SOH\226A'W\186\198\230\134 .D\214?\237+\NAK\181Q%f\166\168\244`*\186 z\GS\183\167q\139\239\DLE\241\DC4\184Z\253\142jJ-P\169\141\203\215I\212\166\251\130\247\254\US\235\RS\156\238\236Z\SOH\NUL....
```

But it seems to be utf-8

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css"/>
...
<script src="//kastatic.com/js/all-df6d9f0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
....
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Edit:

I am not a webguy but it seems that they are encoding their html and decode it via javascript.

Comment: I don't think so this is a problem with the Haskell code. Doing a `curl` to `kickass.to` leads to the same problem.

Comment: @Sibi I have no experience in web development. Is this common to encode html like this?

Comment: This is a gzipped html, http protocol supports compressed content. I suppose you need to parse response headers and decompress the content manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This downloads the content properly:

```
import Data.Conduit.Binary (sinkFile)
import Network.HTTP.Conduit
import qualified Data.Conduit as C

main :: IO ()
main = do
     uri <- parseUrl "http://kickass.to"
     let request = uri {
           decompress = browserDecompress
                       } 
     withManager $ \manager -> do
         response <- http request manager
         responseBody response C.$$+- sinkFile "kickass.html"
```

The `decompress` field will decompress the gzipped data on the fly by using the function `browserDecompress`.